# String slicing nomenclature

Tags: single-word-requests, computing

Maybe I'm just not very good with Google, but I'm looking for good terms to use when describing manipulation of strings of characters, specifically words to describe:

- Removing a prefix
- Removing a suffix
- Removing an infix, i.e. taking out some middle part and concatenating the remaining parts

  A more or less comprehensive list of string manipulation terminology would be nice, but just providing the above definitions would suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at various string-manipulation libraries, tools, and programming languages, you will see a variety of different verbs used here, most of which are general and not location specific.

- remove  — anywhere
- delete — anywhere
- strip  — usually anywhere
- trim  — usually on the two ends only: front/rear or left/right
- splice  — either medial only, or anywhere
- chop, chomp — the rear end

Since there is little consensus here, you should probably just be explicit in your language:

```
s/^string//;      # delete_from_front(), remove_leading()
s/string$//;      # delete_from_end(), remove_trailing()
s/string//g;      # delete_all(), remove_all()
```

Comment: I think I've also seen `lop` for cutting off an end but don't have a reference

Comment: I think there's usually a difference between "strip off" and "strip out" (of course, "off" or "out" may be implied in a method/function name, which may lead to confusion).